# monitoring the click event on the maximizing button on the control box

Tags: winforms

I am creating an windows form application and I want to know how to check when the maximize button is clicked.

Can someone please help me?

The re-size even handler is not detecting when the form is maximized or normal.

And I don't see any event handler for the maximize button on the control box.

Or is there any script in windows form that constantly run over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook up into ClientSizeChanged event. In this event you can monitor WindowState.

To show a messagebox when window is maximized, add following code into forms ClientSizeChanged event:

```
If(WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Maximized")
}
```